# PHP PDO filter function

Tags: php, filter

I'm trying to make filters for a hotels booking, and I can't resolve this. If anyone can help me with some instructions, it would be very helpful. My filter option will be to chose a city, type of room and/or price.

```
function filterOffers(){
    $conn = connectDB();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM offer WHERE ";

    if (isset($_POST['judet_id']) && strlen($_POST['judet_id'])>0){
        $query .= " judet_id LIKE :judet_id";
    }



    if (isset($_POST['tip_camera']) && (intval($_POST['tip_camera'])==1 or intval($_POST['tip_camera']) == 2 or intval($_POST['tip_camera']) == 3) ){
        $query .= " and tip_camera = :tip_camera";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['rating']) && (intval($_POST['rating']) > 1 or intval($_POST['rating']) < 5) ){
        $query .= " and 0 < :rating";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['type']) && (intval($_POST['type'])==1 or intval($_POST['type']) == 2) ){
        $query .= " and type = :type";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['pret']) && intval($_POST['pret']) > 0 ){
        $query .= " and 0 < :pret";
    }

    $query .= " and status=1 ORDER BY id ASC";

    $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);

    if (isset($_POST['judet_id']) && strlen($_POST['judet_id'])>0){
        $stmt->bindParam(":judet_id","%".$_POST['judet_id']."%");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['tip_camera']) && (intval($_POST['tip_camera'])==1 or intval($_POST['tip_camera']) == 2 or intval($_POST['tip_camera']) == 3) ){
        $stmt->bindParam(":tip_camera",intval($_POST['tip_camera']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['rating']) && (intval($_POST['rating']) > 1 or intval($_POST['rating']) < 5) ){
        $rating=$_POST['rating'];
        $stmt->bindParam(":rating",$rating);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['type']) && (intval($_POST['type'])==1 or intval($_POST['type']) == 2) ){
        $stmt->bindParam(":type",intval($_POST['type']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['pret']) && intval($_POST['pret']) > 0 ){
        $stmt->bindParam(":pret",intval($_POST['pret']));
    }
    // echo $query;
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = array();

    while ($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $results[]=$result;
    }

    return results;
} // end function

if(isset($_POST['filtrare'])){
    $ultimileOferte=filterOffers();
    // echo "die";die();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem actually?

Comment: Use double pipes `||` instead of `or` in your conditionals.  use `>` and `<` instead of 3 separate statements for `tip_camera`.  I think you are calling `intval()` too much; you can store it while checking it like this: `($pret=intval($_POST['pret']))>0` then you can just use `$pret` in `bindParam`  Of course, you can/should repeat this technique for all $_POST data in this script.

Comment: What issue you are facing?